# can tightVNC be used to share a particular application window, rather the whole desktop?

Tags: vnc

I want to share only an application window to a remote user. I don't need whole desktop sharing. Is it possible to use tightVNC for this purpose? there is http://shared-app-vnc.sourceforge.net/ which does just that. But it doesn't seem to have applet support.

Answer (score 0):

TightVNC version 1.3.10 can share a particular window.

TightVNC version 2 does not allow to share a part of the desktop yet. This functionality will be implemented in future versions.

Best Regards,
Constantin