# Is there a way to host a website that provides an rdp connection to a browser application on a remote computer?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, browser, vnc

I am attempting to provide my non-tech-savvy friends a way to browse a website with a vpn without directly configuring a proxy/vpn on their machine. I'm trying to make a website that provides a remote desktop connection to a browser that is routed through a vpn to achieve that goal. The setup I was thinking of is a VM that hosts a vnc server as there are some vnc clients that can use just http(noVNC). The issue is in the details. I want all users to be locked to a browser application that is locked to a specific website and I want all downloads to be routed to their local browser. I'm hoping someone can't point to an existing app or knows how to configure rdp to do this. Any tips or even completely different solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create RemoteApp in the windows server, and publish it through Remote Desktop Services.

For X11 you can use xpra in seamless mode, xpra supports html5 client
https://superuser.com/a/393866/565702

```
xpra start-desktop --start-child=browser
```

[sample video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ukqs5M5Fthg)